# pandas : px.parallel_coordinates, how to adjust interval of each axe?

Tags: pandas, parallel-coordinates

I'm currently working on pandas, and trying to make a 'good-looking' parallel coordinates using px.parallel_coordinates function.

Automatically, it makes a graph with a fixed interval [min_value;max_value].

I want to have an interval such as [0 ; max_value].

Does anyone can help me with it please?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you elaborate on the px.parellel_coordinate function? what the data sample? px stands for?

Comment: Sounds like he's using Plotly Express, often imported as `import plotly.express as px`.